# How do we see the picture of an object as a whole thing in spherical mirrors?

Tags: optics, reflection, vision

When we see an object in a spherical mirror, the different parts of the object has different pictures which are also at different locations compared to each other.

The lights that go from the tip of the object reflect and intersect at a point. But the lights that go from the middle of the object reflect and intersect at a different point. We can emit lights from each part of the object, and all of them reflect and intersect at different points.

So how do we see the picture of an object as a whole thing in a spherical mirror while the different parts of the object have different pictures?

[image: Mirror]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is precisely *because* the light emanating from different parts of the object converges at different points on your retina that you are able to clearly see the object. If all of that light arrived at the same point on your retina, then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between its different parts and it would just look like a bright blob.

Similarly, if the light from different points overlapped on your retina, then the object would look blurry - which is precisely what happens when you are nearsighted or farsighted. If the optical power of your eye is too great or small, then the light is focused too soon or too late and the light that actually reaches your retina comes from more than just one point of the object.

[image]

[Source](http://www.mstworkbooks.co.za/natural-sciences/gr8/gr8-ec-04.html)

The same principle applies if you're talking about the image formed on a screen rather than on your retina. Different parts of the object are mapped onto different parts of the image - otherwise the whole thing would be a single bright spot.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But you forgot the mirror thing

Comment: When I say intersect at a point I don't mean intersecting at retina. I mean the reflection of the lights that comeback from the mirror and intersect between the mirror and you.

Comment: As you can see in the added picture, the blue light beams go from the tip of the object and hit the mirror. The reflections intersect at a point. On the other hand, the purple light beams go from the middle of the object and the reflections meet at another point. So the picture of the tip of the object differs from the picture of middle of the object spatially. If you draw the parabola and lights in a cartesian plane the differences will be more obvious. Also, they aren't aligned in a vertical line.

Comment: @SnackExchange It's the same principle, but I've amended my answer to include a diagram.

Comment: @SnackExchange It sounds like you understand what's happening, but the question seems backward. If you imagine that all of the light which comes from the object reflects off the mirror and comes together to a single point, then how could you possibly identify a recognizable image, whose different parts must *necessarily* be separated spatially?

Comment: When we want to determine the location of the picture of a vertical object and its height we just draw the beams from the tip of the object to the mirror and draw the picture from the intersection point, ignoring other intersection points that aren't on the picture line.

Comment: @SnackExchange I'm not sure what you're trying to say. A clear image is formed if the light coming from each point of the object is reflected and focused down to a single, unique point on the screen. There must be a one-to-one correspondence between points on the object and points on the image, otherwise the image would become an unrecognizable blur, with the light from different points on the object mixing together.

Comment: @SnackExchange You seem to be asking how there can be a clear image on the screen if the light from the Mona Lisa's hands is reflected and focused to a different point than the light from the Mona Lisa's nose. My point is that it is precisely *because* the light from the nose and the light from the hands arrive at different points on the screen that the image is clear in the first place. If all the light arrived at the same point, there would be no image - just a bright spot.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is not an exact construct, F is not right for tis mirror, so it seems the converging rays meet at very different vertical points. If you use a spherical mirror one uses only a small part near the middle, than the image points are (allmost)  on a vertical line. Of cause the points are different, so light from different points come to your ey or the camera from these , but if you look at the original object, the light from different point come the same way to your ey. If rays from different points would come together at one point, You would not see a picture , but just a lighted point.